# vb.net setting the scale to a chart to maximum

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mschart

I have a line chart in VB using the standard WinForm [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control (`System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`). On the Y axis is the amount of cars, on the X axis is the time. Each point is submitted every hour. it looks like this:

[image: This is the graph]

As you can see the time (X-axis) is displaying correctly, it shows 1 then 2 then 3 and so on.. but as the chart gets bigger it starts removing the grid on the x values, as well as their labels, like so:

[image: Image 2]

Please can someone inform me as to how I can prevent the graph from automatically removing the x values label.

Thank you, and I have not provided code because I have tried everything and none of it seems to work. I have a feeling its somewhere in the properties for the graph.

EDIT:

Here is the code that I use to generate the chart.

```
Dim lightvehicleaveragetime As New Series
lightvehicleaveragetime.Name = "Light Vehicle"
lightvehicleaveragetime.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline
Form3.Chart1.Series.Add(lightvehicleaveragetime
lightvehicleaveragetime.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
lightvehicleaveragetime.BorderWidth = 3
```

The rest of the code runs in a while loop, and everytime the hour changes, it will add:

```
lightvehicleaveragetime.Points.AddXY(hour & ":" & minute & ":" & seconds, alllightvehicleentriesgraphtime)
lightvehicleaveragetime.LabelToolTip = time
lightvehicleaveragetime.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
lightvehicleaveragetime.MarkerSize = 5
lightvehicleaveragetime.MarkerColor = Color.Black
```

Comment: What tool are you using to generate/display the graph?

Comment: I will add my code for generating the chart.

Comment: Added my code to do so

Comment: So, I'm guessing, based on your code, that `Chart1` is either a WinForm [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) control, or a ASP.NET [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx) control?

Comment: Correct. It is a WinForm chart

Comment: I've updated your question and it's tags to properly reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you need to restrict the x axis values to be hours. the interval type or minor/major grids might help. Have you tried

```
  Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours
```

and try setting

```
  Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
```